# How to embed Facebook share on iOS like at attached pic

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I came across an app that I would really love to know what did they used for sharing on Facebook.

The app shows a share button that opens a window (see below image). The share parameters of the share dialog are an image and a URL meaning when I will post it to my wall who ever will tap on it will go the entered URL.

Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with native `SLComposeViewController`.
Just add social media framework. Import that in your project then add following lines:

```
- (IBAction)facebookPost:(id)sender {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"Social Framework sharing test!"];

        [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];

        [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692493/how-to-embed-facebook-share-on-ios-like-at-attached-pic"]];

        [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

             switch (result) {
                 case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                     NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
                     break;
                 case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                     NSLog(@"Post Sucessful");
                     break;

                 default:
                     break;
             }
         }];

        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the url image is replacing the image I added at the code.
Any idea way?

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I added a UIImage and a NSURL in my code.
when the SLComposeViewController is opening it shows an image from the url instead of the UIImage I placed in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have a same issue.

This is caused by below situation.

1 To post both "Image" and "URL".
(using these methods => addImage: addUrl: )

2 To be downloaded Facebook App in your iPhone, and login through the Facebook App.
(if your iPhone has not Facebook App, it doesn't occur.)

I think this is caused by Facebook account's setting.

I have a multiple Facebook test accounts. 
An Facebook test account cause this phenomenon.And switch another facebook account, it doesn't cause this phenomenon.So I guess this is caused by Facebook account's setting.

If you want to post Correctly , there are two ways.

1 Delete Facebook App on your iPhone, and login through device setting Facebook Account.

2 Give up that to post both "image" and "URL".
If you post only one(image or URL),you can post Correctly.

I hope this helps :)